# Flutter code recovery from aab file (Android App Bundle)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, reverse-engineering

I had an issue with my Computer and had to format it. An app was completely erased because my version control was only locally. The app exists on the Google Play store and I have access to the Android App Bundle. Is there a way to recover the flutter code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sadly, practically: no... you may try to "decompile" APK (every "type" of abi/density/lang etc. splits), but still this will give you some Android-specified code, probably still messy, even without minifying. and you are seeking full flutter code, thats impossible

note that: if you could do that, got full code from "compiled" APK/bundle then anyone could do that, steal your code, make clones etc. this "possibility" would be just very unsecure

Comment: Actually I have seen that there are ways to reverse engineer APK files into Flutter, and I thought that the AAB is easier. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: well, technically this is possible, but gets harder when got only "release" apk/aab version, as flutter/dart code is compiled to native ARM code, so in fact this is reverse engineering of `*.so` file, not exacly android-specific extension. still good luck!